# Pandas - InvalidIndexError on concat

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple concat:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(),df2.reset_index()],ignore_index = True)
```

That throws the following error:

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index
> objects

I can't seem to figure out why though (I added the reset_index and ignore_index to try and fix the issue, but no luck).

For info on the indicies:

```
df1.index = RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
df2.index = RangeIndex(start=0, stop=42, step=1)
```

Could this be a column specific issue?  There are a lot of overlapping columns between df1 and df2 (but each one does have some unique columns as well).

Thanks!

Comment: I am just curious, whether you have duplicated column name? Duplicate column names created this problem on my dataset.

Comment: oh, maybe I do.  duplicate col names within one dataframe?  Or duplicate / shared col names between the two dataframes?

Comment: In one data frame.

Comment: Ah, that could be it! Trying to fix that now, thx a lot